# Invalid column name "SENOKO" (SQL Queries)

Tags: sql

I have done a query which I would like to add a "SENOKO" column that calculate the sum by using the fields in a database. If I did not Group By SENOKO, then repeated result will be shown in report. 
To avoid repeated record, I was thinking to Group By the SENOKO, but error shown up as follow:

> Invalid column name "SENOKO"

```
SELECT customer.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level, whbal.stock_type, (SELECT SUM((CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 3), qty_good) + CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 3), qty_slack)) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 3), std_weight) / 1000) FROM whbal WHERE warehouse='SKW')AS SENOKO 
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN whbal ON customer.customer=whbal.customer 
INNER JOIN stktype ON whbal.stock_type=stktype.stock_type 
WHERE customer.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2 AND whbal.stock_type=@type 
GROUP BY customer.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level, whbal.stock_type, SENOKO
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SENOKO` is derived column, so you can't use it directly in `GROUP BY` clause.

Use this:

```
select * from (
SELECT customer.customer, customer.imp_license_no, customer.psq_level, whbal.stock_type, (SELECT SUM((CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 3), qty_good) + CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 3), qty_slack)) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 3), std_weight) / 1000) FROM whbal WHERE warehouse='SKW')AS SENOKO 
FROM customer 
INNER JOIN whbal ON customer.customer=whbal.customer 
INNER JOIN stktype ON whbal.stock_type=stktype.stock_type 
WHERE customer.customer BETWEEN @cust1 AND @cust2 AND whbal.stock_type=@type 
) as subquery
GROUP BY subquery.customer, subquery.imp_license_no, subquery.psq_level, subquery.stock_type, Subquery.SENOKO
```

Comment: Another error shown up:

    **Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.**

Comment: pls help .. appreciated

Comment: New error: 
**Invalid Column name "customer"
Invalid Column Name "stock_type"
Invalid COlumn Name "Stock"**